# How to use a for loop and splice to remove a word and then check an array for a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, string

I want to make a function that looks for a specific name (Inger) in an array, and the removes that name. Then I want the function to tell that a name doesn't exist in the array.

```
    var femaleName = ["Anne","Inger","Kari","Marit","Ingrid"]

    function removeElement (aTable, aName) {

        for (var i = 0; i <= aTable.length - 1; i++) {
            if (aTable[1] === aName) {

                aTable.splice(i, 1)
                document.write(aTable); {break;}

            } else if (aTable[i] !== aName) {
                document.write(aName + " is not in the list");
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to solve it this way, but I don't get it right. The output should be something like this:

```
Anne, Kari, Marit, Ingrid
Victoria is not in the list
```

Comment: why is `break` wrapped in a block?

Comment: I am missing where you assign the array femaleName to your aTable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to write functions? Javascript has Array methods to do this for you.

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
var femaleName = ["Anne", "Inger", "Kari", "Marit", "Ingrid"]

femaleName = femaleName.filter(name => name !== 'Inger')

console.log(femaleName);

console.log(femaleName.includes('Inger'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this line:

```
if (aTable[1] === aName) {
```

That only checks the second index (`"Inger"`). It should be this:

```
if (aTable[i] === aName) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
function removeElement(aTable, aName) {
    const index = aTable.indexOf(aName);
    if (index > -1) {
        aTable.splice(index, 1);
        document.write(aTable);
    } else {
        document.write(aName + " is not in the list");
    }
}
```

Or you could always use functional Array.prototype.filter().

Answer (score 1):

Following your description, try this example. That first gets the index in the array of the searched name using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), then removes it from the array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and finally prints the result

```js
const names = ['Anne', 'Inger', 'Kari', 'Marit', 'Ingrid'];

function notify(criteria) {
    const position = getPosition(criteria);
    const removed = removeName(position);
    
    console.log(names);
    console.log(`${removed} is not in the list`);
}

function getPosition(criteria) {
    return names.findIndex(name => name === criteria);
}

function removeName(position) {
    return names.splice(position, 1);
}

notify('Inger');
```